# Retrieve NotSentEvent

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap

I am trying to retrieve a NotSentEvent using the SOAP API. The response I get back from ExactTarget is a timeout message.

I am wondering if there is some better filtering that I can do, besides just a date range and subscriber key, that will allow my results to come back?

Here is my message:

```
<ns1:Body>
<ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
  <ns0:RetrieveRequest>
    <ns0:ObjectType>NotSentEvent</ns0:ObjectType>
    <ns0:Properties>TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID</ns0:Properties>
    <ns0:Properties>SendID</ns0:Properties>
    <ns0:Properties>SubscriberKey</ns0:Properties>
    <ns0:Properties>EventDate</ns0:Properties>
    <ns0:Properties>EventType</ns0:Properties>
    <ns0:Properties>BatchID</ns0:Properties>
    <ns0:Filter xsi:type="ns0:ComplexFilterPart">
      <ns0:LeftOperand xsi:type="ns0:SimpleFilterPart">
        <ns0:Property>SubscriberKey</ns0:Property>
        <ns0:SimpleOperator>equals</ns0:SimpleOperator>
        <ns0:Value>xxxxxx-removed@gmail.com</ns0:Value>
      </ns0:LeftOperand>
      <ns0:LogicalOperator>AND</ns0:LogicalOperator>
      <ns0:RightOperand xsi:type="ns0:SimpleFilterPart">
        <ns0:Property>EventDate</ns0:Property>
        <ns0:SimpleOperator>between</ns0:SimpleOperator>
        <ns0:DateValue>2014-05-01</ns0:DateValue>
        <ns0:DateValue>2014-05-02</ns0:DateValue>
      </ns0:RightOperand>
    </ns0:Filter>
  </ns0:RetrieveRequest>
</ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
</ns1:Body>
```

And the response from ET:

```
<soap:Body>
<RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <OverallStatus>Error: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.</OverallStatus>
  <RequestID>xxxxxx-removed</RequestID>
</RetrieveResponseMsg>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I can get a response by filtering based on SendID or Client.ID.

Here are the examples:

**SendID**

```
<ns1:Body>
  <ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
    <ns0:RetrieveRequest>
      <ns0:ObjectType>NotSentEvent</ns0:ObjectType>
      <ns0:Properties>TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>SendID</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>SubscriberKey</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>EventDate</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>EventType</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>BatchID</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Filter xsi:type="ns0:SimpleFilterPart">
        <ns0:Property>SendID</ns0:Property>
        <ns0:SimpleOperator>equals</ns0:SimpleOperator>
        <ns0:Value>123456</ns0:Value>
      </ns0:Filter>
    </ns0:RetrieveRequest>
  </ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
</ns1:Body>
```

**Client.ID (The accounts MID)**

```
<ns1:Body>
  <ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
    <ns0:RetrieveRequest>
      <ns0:ObjectType>NotSentEvent</ns0:ObjectType>
      <ns0:Properties>TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>SendID</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>SubscriberKey</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>EventDate</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>EventType</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Properties>BatchID</ns0:Properties>
      <ns0:Filter xsi:type="ns0:SimpleFilterPart">
        <ns0:Property>Client.ID</ns0:Property>
        <ns0:SimpleOperator>equals</ns0:SimpleOperator>
        <ns0:Value>123456</ns0:Value>
      </ns0:Filter>
    </ns0:RetrieveRequest>
  </ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
</ns1:Body>
```